# Formik show validation error message after seperating into components

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have trying to add formik validation to my form after splitting it into diff components (A seperate component for my input boxes) so the structure is like

Parent Ccomponent.js

```
import Input from "../containers/input";  //this is another component which i am using as a child here 
export default function Signup(props) {
  const {
    handleSubmit,
    handleChange,
    handleBlur,
    values,
    errors,
    touched,
  } = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      email: ""
    },
    validationSchema,
    onSubmit(values) {
      console.log("executed");
      console.log(values);
    },
  });

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Navbar />
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="container" id="signup">      
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-lg-12 ">
                  <Input
                    type="text"
                    name="email"
                    placeholder="Email"
                    handleChange={handleChange}
                    handleBlur={handleBlur}
                    touched={touched}
                    errors={errors}
                  />
                </div>               
            </div>
            <div className="row registerButtonDiv">
              <button className="registerButton openSans" type="submit">
                REGISTER
              </button>
            </div>
        
      </form>

    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

So now Input component is my child components and i have passed all formik methods here

Input.js

```
export default function Input(props) {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="inputContainer">
        <input
          type={props.type}
          placeholder={props.placeholder}
          name={props.name}
          className="inputTextBox"
          onChange={props.handleChange}
          onBlur={props.handleBlur}
        />
        <StarIcon />
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

So far everything works fine but what if i want to show validation error meassge below the input box if it's there??

So far we do something like

```
 {touched.name && errors.name && <div>{errors.name}</div>}
```

but now here i am getting everything by props how would i rewrite this line, for sure i cant rewrite it as

```
{props.touched.props.name && props.errors.props.name&&<div>{props.errors.props.name</div>}
```

Comment: `for sure i cant rewrite it as` why not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make props from parent like this :

```
onError={touched.email && errors.email}
```

then on child use it like this :

```
<p>{props.onError}</p>
```